# Java switch fallthrough

Tags: java

*Note: Used Eclipse Luna (4.4 R) with ADT 23.0.2*

I've been following Google's guide on how to develop android applications, and along the way I decided to run the code step by step out of curiosity where the execution jumps into when I press on the action bar.  I came across this curious feature and I don't know why it's happening.

Basically, the action bar code has this switch statement:

```
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            openSearch();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            openSettings();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

So, I placed a breakpoint at the switch line and when I touched the action bar, the switch would normally go to the case that corresponds to the id of icon that was touched.

However, the execution also goes through the default case.  My previous understanding was that default is only executed if none of the cases matched, so why is the default case also being executed in this scenario?  Won't the method already exit after encountering the return statement in each case? Is this a feature of java switch statements?

---

**Update:** (As suggested in the comments below...)

So to test it out, I declared a local var to store the id, but I also added an extra line in the default block.  The revised code is below:

```
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    int id = item.getItemId(); 
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            openSearch();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            openSettings();
            return true;
        default:
            id = 0;
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Like mentioned above, one of the cases is executed, AND the default return is also highlighted, but the id assignment to 0 is skipped over (NOT executed).  So I think this is a debugger only feature.  LOL.  It's severely misleading.  =(

Comment: @jhobbie:  If you add `return` after each of those cases, then `break` is unreachable code.

Comment: @jhobbie - He has `return` at the end of each `case`.  Adding `break` will just cause a compiler error message.

Comment: Does your `item.getItemId()` value match any of those cases?

Comment: Is the default code actually being executed with another case being executed as well, or is the debugger just visually jumping to the end of switch statement?

Comment: Consider logging the id value.

Comment: Interesting, I expected the easy solution and became blind for the obvious!

Comment: I didn't write the code above, it was copy-pasted from the guide at Google Android developer website.  The android app works fine, I'm just curious why the default case is also being executed despite having a match in one of the cases.  @NESPowerGlove That crossed my mind too, but how to know if that's happening or not?

Comment: As @NESPowerGlove suggests, sometimes the debugger can fool you and make it appear that control is jumping where it isn't.

Comment: @NESPowerGlove that's a good point. I'm wondering though, why would it even jump to the default statement in the debugger? Once it hits the return statement, shouldn't it exit from inside the method?

Comment: At Poly - are you sure it's actually being executed? I have seen some IDEs where the stepper will highlight the default switch even if it isn't being executed. I like @Hot's idea of logging the id value, to see where it's really entering and exiting.

Comment: @jhobbie - It may be that both `return` statements branch to the same location, near the `finally` code.  It may be that there's a surrounding `try/finally` block that needs to be executed.  It may be that the debugger just wants to drive you crazy.  (Debuggers are like that, you know -- something evil in all of them.)

Comment: @HotLicks As I understood your suggestion, I placed the id in a local var.  The debugger really does execute the default return because the local watch still preserves until after the default is executed.  Is this what you meant by logging the id?

Comment: @jhobbie I don't know. It could be a "feature" of the debugger, or some low level construct of the byte code, or it could be jumping to a finally like Hot Licks says but visually is not matching up your compiled code to source code correctly.

Comment: I would point out that you're not showing us the real code.  You can't have a valueless return in one place in your method and a return with value in another.

Comment: And my suggestion was to LOG the id value (eg, `System.out.println("The id value is " + item.getItemId());`).

Comment: @HotLicks Okay, I understand. Sorry for the misunderstanding but your suggestion was helpful! =)  There's nothing to show really, it's all the codes in the guide I followed which is publicly accessible to anyone.

Comment: I'd say it's working but you're just thinking that you're debugging the right way but you're not. Print the ID before you enter the switch.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is not jumping unpredictably to the `default` case, here is a simple proof:

```
public class SO {
    public static boolean caseTest(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("Case 0:");
                return true;
            default:
                System.out.println("Default Case:");
                return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Returned:"+caseTest(0));
        //Prints:
        //Case 0:
        //Returned:true

        System.out.println("Returned:"+caseTest(1));
        //Prints:
        //Default Case:
        //Returned:false
    }
}
```

Now for things that could be the issue, take a look at the values of `R.id.action_search` and `R.id.action_settings`, they may not be what you think.